# Export PYTHONPATH - syntax error

Tags: python, shell, path, module, syntax-error

I need to connect MySQLdb - module.

I download MySQLdb - module and install it.

But when i write (in python interactive shell): `import MySQLdb` - i get `no module named MySQLdb`.

Then i decided to include MySQLdb directory in PYTHONPATH variable.

I write (in python interactive shell): 
`export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/where/module/lives/`

And in response i receive a syntax error: `invalid syntax`: export PYTHONPATH`^`=${PYTHONPATH}:/where/module/lives/

What's wrong with syntax here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you really mean you are typing

```
 >>> export PYTHONPATH...
```

in the Python "interactive shell", the syntax error is because it is not valid Python, it is a command (bash) shell statement:

```
 $ export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/where/module/lives/"
 $ python
 Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56)
 >>> import MySQLdb
 >>>
```

Comment: Should the colon in that bash statement be a semicolon? Don't you want `/some/path` to become `/some/path;/where/the/module/lives/`?

Comment: Semi-colons are [path separators on Windows and colons do the job on Unix](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH). The question used Unix syntax even though the OP didn't explicitly say what OS was being used.

Comment: Just when I thought I was getting OK at Linux, there's something really basic I didn't know!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to modify the path to packages from within Python, you can do:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/where/module/lives/')
```

The syntax `export PYTHONPATH=…` is understood by (Bourne) shells (bash, etc.).

Both uses have their advantage:

- For modules that are not used often, the "within" Python approach is often best, since you do not have to pollute PYTHONPATH with the path to all minor modules.
- For modules that are used in many programs, the shell approach is often best; in this case, you can permanently modify PYTHONPATH by updating it in you shell initialization file (`.bashrc`, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

If you want the change to be permanent , then append this line in ~/.bashrc

```
 export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```